# Mark rows from one table where value exists in join table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For my query, I have two tables, as defined below:

**permissions** table:

```
| permission_id | permission_description |
|---------------|------------------------|
|             1 | Create User            |
|             2 | Edit User              |
|             3 | Delete User            |
```

**users_permissions** table:

```
| permission_id | user_id |
|---------------|---------|
|             1 |       1 |
|             1 |       2 |
|             3 |       2 |
|             3 |       5 |
|             1 |       3 |
|             3 |       1 |
```

Now, I need to retrieve a list of **all** permissions in the `permissions` table, with a column to indicate if the user with `user_id` of `1` exists for each permission in the `users_permissions` table.

So, my **desired output** for the query would be:

```
| permission_id | permission_description | has_permission |
|---------------|------------------------|----------------|
|             1 | Create User            | TRUE           |
|             2 | Edit User              | FALSE          |
|             3 | Delete User            | TRUE           |
```

---

So far, I have tried the following query, but it returns entries for all `permissions` and all `user_id` values:

```
SELECT permissions.permission_id,
       permission_description,
       CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS has_permission
FROM permissions
       INNER JOIN users_permissions ON permission.permission_id = users_permissions.permissions_id;
```

How do I limit that to just one entry per `permission`?

---

For clarity, the end goal is to get a list of available permissions and mark the ones the user already has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know the answer for one user then an `exists subquery` will do the job - no need for a join.

```
SELECT P.permission_id
  , P.permission_description
  , CASE WHEN exists (select 1 from users_permissions UP where UP.permission_id = P.permission_id and UP.user_id = 1) THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS has_permission
FROM [permissions] P
```

PS - I wouldn't recommend having a table called `permissions` as its a reserved word in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` and check `if it is null`

```
select permissions.permission_id,
       permission_description,
       case when user_id is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' END as has_permission
FROM permissions
LEFT JOIN users_permissions 
  ON permission.permission_id = users_permissions.permissions_id and user_id = 1
```